# Give unique class name to every appended div

Tags: jquery, html, class, append

I'm trying to give a unique class name to every div I append. Specifically referring to the div with class "movehere-#" I'd like it to look like this:

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="movehere-0">
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="movehere-1">
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="movehere-2">
  </div>
</section>
```

This is the original code. The JQuery adds a div to every 3rd, and at the very end. It appends with the class "movehere". How do you give it a unique class "movehere-#"?

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>

<script>

$("div > div:nth-child(3n), div:last-child")
.after('<div class="movehere"></div>');
</script>
```

I'm a beginner coder and would appreciate any explanations :)

Comment: Incremental classes are generally a code smell. Is there a specific reason you need to do this? I ask as there is likely to be a better, more extensible approach

Comment: Why is that? I'm new to jquery and the big picture solution I'm  trying to find is to append a list of divs and sections (from wordpress) into a specific layout. Regarding the 3 divs above "movehere-0", say they will be click button 1 2 and 3. Inside the div "movehere-0" will be 3 <articles>'s for 1 2 and 3 that are appended. And so on

Comment: Let me try to reword that -  I plan to append 3 <div> inside ".movehere-0" that are related to the 3 divs above ".movehere-0". There will be 3 <div> inside ".movehere-1" that are related to the 3 <div> above ".movehere-1." I thought have a variable set with "i" would be the easiest way to add it in :\ though I'm not sure

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
$('section > div:nth-child(3n)').each(function(i,x) {
  $(this).addClass("movehere-" + i);
})
```

This will add a class to every 3'rd div in your section.

**Demo**

```js
$('section > div:nth-child(3n)').each(function(i, x) {
  $(this).addClass("movehere-" + i);
})
```

```css
div[class^="movehere"] {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</section>
```

Comment: It works!! I never thought to use a second function to add a class. Thank you :)

Comment: @MelissaGinoza No problem, happy to help